# Java : Save Assigned String from method in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, constructor

I'm having trouble trying to save a assigned `String` and `String[]` from a constructor method into an array and then print it out.
The idea behind the program is adding a person to the doodle program with their name and their answers (in `voegDeelnameToe`) and then print out all the information trough `geefPollInfo()`.

I'm trying to add 6 person trough the voegDeelnameToe() method but I can't save the
`String deelnemer` (= String 'name of participant')
and
`String[] aanwezigheden` (= String[] 'answers')

in another object and then print it out.

```
doodle.voegDeelnameToe("Bram",new String[]{"ja", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "ja", "nee", "nee", "nee", "ja", "ja", "ja"});
doodle.voegDeelnameToe("Katja", new String[]{"nee", "nee", "ja", "nee", "nee", "nee", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja"});
doodle.voegDeelnameToe("Kristien", new String[]{"ja", "ja", "ja", "ja", "nee", "nee", "nee", "nee", "nee", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja"});
doodle.voegDeelnameToe("Peter", new String[]{"ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "nee", "nee", "nee", "nee", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja"});
doodle.voegDeelnameToe("Sven", new String[]{"nee", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "nee", "nee", "nee", "nee", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "ja", "ja"});
doodle.voegDeelnameToe("Matthias", new String[]{"ja", "ja", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja", "nee", "nee", "nee", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja"});
System.out.println(doodle.geefPollInfo());`
```

The class :

```
public class Poll {

    boolean type;
    String titel;
    String omschrijving;
    String locatie;
    String initiator;
    final int MAX_DEELNEMERS = 10;
    LocalDate[] data;
    LocalTime[] tijdstippen;
    String[] deelnemers = new String[] {"","","","","","",};
    String[] antwoorden = new String[15];
    String[][] poll = new String[6][15];
    String einde = " ";
    boolean afgesloten;
    int teller = 1;

    public Poll(String testBasispoll_1, String dit_is_de_eerste_basispoll, String location, String name, LocalDate[] data, LocalTime[] tijdstippen, boolean b) {
         titel = testBasispoll_1;
         omschrijving = dit_is_de_eerste_basispoll;
         locatie = location;
         initiator = name;
         this.data = data;
         this.tijdstippen = tijdstippen;
         type = b;


    } 


    public String geefPollInfo() {

        System.out.println("Titel : " + titel);
        System.out.println("Omschrijving : " + omschrijving);
        System.out.println("Locatie : " + locatie);
        System.out.println("Initiator : " + initiator);
        System.out.println("Max aantal deelnemers : " + MAX_DEELNEMERS);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Dag \t \t" + data[0] + "\t \t" + data[1] + "\t \t" + data[2] + "\t \t" + data[3] + "\t \t" + data[4]);
        System.out.println("Uur \t \t" + tijdstippen[0] + "\t" + tijdstippen[1] + "\t" + tijdstippen[2] + "\t" + tijdstippen[0] + "\t" + tijdstippen[1] + "\t" + tijdstippen[2] + "\t" + tijdstippen[0] + "\t" + tijdstippen[1] + "\t" + tijdstippen[2] + "\t" + tijdstippen[0] + "\t" + tijdstippen[1] + "\t" + tijdstippen[2] + "\t" + tijdstippen[0] + "\t" + tijdstippen[1] + "\t" + tijdstippen[2]);


        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println(deelnemers[i] + "\t");
        }

            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) { 
                System.out.print(antwoorden[j] + "\t");

            }




        return einde;
    }

    public boolean voegDeelnameToe(String deelnemer, String[] aanwezigheden) {

        //for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                antwoorden[j] = aanwezigheden[j];
            }            
       // }   
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            deelnemers[i] = deelnemer;

        }


      return type;
    }
```

Comment: You are printing the returned String from geefPollInfo() which is the variable einde. einde is just a " " character and I don't see it re-initialised anywhere. I'm not sure what u r trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `voegDeelnameToe` will (over)write all elements of *antwoorden* and *antwoorden* each time you call it. Therefore only the last person *Matthias* will remain in *Poll*. Suggestions :

1. Modify `voegDeelnameToe` signature to something like `boolean voegDeelnameToe(int personIndex, String deelnemer, String[] aanwezigheden)`. Then skip the second for loop and just do `deelnemers[index] = deelnemer;`. I am not sure what you are supposed to do with `aanwezigheden` in this case.
2. Create a field `int index = 0;` in `Poll` and increment it each time `voegDeelnameToe` is called as long as it is lower than 6. E.g:

   ```
   deelnemers[index] = deelnemer;
   ++index;`
   ```

I have to point out that there is a field `String[][] poll = new String[6][15];` in `Poll` class that seems like it is supposed to hold the results of the poll. You are probably supposed to store `aanwezigheden` there for each of the 6 participants ? Otherwise `antwoorden` get overwritten every time. For example, if you add a field in `int index = 0;` in `Poll`, the method `voegDeelnameToe` would look something like this :

```
public boolean voegDeelnameToe(String deelnemer, String[] aanwezigheden) {
    if (index < poll.length && index < deelnemers.length) {
        deelnemers[index] = deelnemer;
        System.arraycopy(aanwezigheden, 0, poll[index], 0, aanwezigheden.length);
        ++index;
    }
    return type;
}
```

Note that you should check if index is within array bounds in such cases and that `System.arraycopy` is more efficient and arguably simpler than a for loop for copying arrays.

Comment: Yes, the original purpose is storing the aanwezigheden and antwoorden in String[][] poll = new String[6][15]; Because I couldn't figure it out, I tried it in different ways. If u have any suggestions to find a solution with the String[][] poll = new String[6][15]; it would be very appreciated.